# install drivers for wifi card AX200 WIE7265

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

apologies for my ignorance in advance. I bought the wifi AX200 WIE7265 card for my computer but it is performing very badly and I have to install the proper drivers for this.
I am definitely a complete ignorant about all of this and I am trying to learn more about Linux and specifically xubuntu (that I currently have on my computer).
Can someone tell me how I install the new driver for the wifi card? Like showing me all the steps.

Thank you

I have run the commands and the results are:

```
[    7.956325] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.965912] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.965945] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.970525] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    7.970528] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    7.970529] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    7.970916] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.054021] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    8.065456] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.066037] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    8.220377] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: base HW address: c8:e2:65:5e:d0:21
[    8.235516] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
[   10.760067] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   10.908416] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

And

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0084]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Basically internet connection is very slow it never drops but takes ages to open whatever kind of website.

Comment: I don't believe there is a new *driver* but there may be, in fact, newer *firmware*. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Finally, please explain more fully what you mean: "it is performing very badly " Is it slow? Drops? Fails to connect?? Or what?

Comment: thank you for your help. I have edited the question with the results

Answer (score 0):

We see in your readings that the driver loads verson 48 of the firmware:

> loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm

There are several newer firmware versions available. Let's install them and see if speed improves. From the terminal:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.190_all.deb
ar -x linux*
tar -xf data*
cd lib/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-cc-a0*  /usr/lib/firmware
```

Next, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Your wireless may be struggling because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Finally, be certain that DNS resolution is working correctly. Check:

```
ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
```

resolv.conf should be a symbolic link pointing to systemd. If not, please do:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf  /etc/resolv.conf
```

After a reboot, is there any improvement?